# Terraform Output doesn't exist after running terraform apply

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I configure my terraform using a GCS backend, with a workspace. My CI environment exactly has access to the state file it requires for the workspace.

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.14"

  backend "gcs" {
    prefix      = "<my prefix>"
    bucket      = "<my bucket>"
    credentials = "credentials.json"
  }
}
```

I define the output of my terraform module inside `output.tf`:

```
output "base_api_url" {
  description = "Base url for the deployed cloud run service"
  value = google_cloud_run_service.api.status[0].url
}
```

My CI Server runs `terraform apply -auto-approve -lock-timeout 15m`. It succeeds and it shows me the output in the console logs:

```
Outputs:

base_api_url = "https://<my project url>.run.app"
```

When I call `terraform output base_api_url` and it gives me the following error:

```
│ Warning: No outputs found
│ 
│ The state file either has no outputs defined, or all the defined outputs
│ are empty. Please define an output in your configuration with the `output`
│ keyword and run `terraform refresh` for it to become available. If you are
│ using interpolation, please verify the interpolated value is not empty. You
│ can use the `terraform console` command to assist.
```

I try calling `terraform refresh` like it mentions in the warning and it tells me:

```
╷
│ Warning: Empty or non-existent state
│ 
│ There are currently no remote objects tracked in the state, so there is
│ nothing to refresh.
╵
```

I'm not sure what to do. I'm calling `terraform output` RIGHT after I call apply, but it's still giving me no outputs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Everything is happening in the same pipeline?

Comment: Can you confirm that the CI and your machine are using the same workspace? Does the machine giving errors also have access to the bucket with the state file?

Comment: This does definitely sound like different backends.

Comment: These are happening as separate steps in the same ci job.

Comment: Are the two steps happening in exactly the same filesystem directory? It seems like the steps running after the apply step aren't able to find the `backend "gcs"` setting and are therefore defaulting to looking for local state files instead, or perhaps that the GCS credentials are invalid in some way which makes the underlying system return a "not found" error instead of an authorization error, and thus confuses Terraform. 

Comment: Running your `terraform output` command with the environment variable `TF_LOG=trace` set might give some additional pointers. That output is intended more as an aid for development of Terraform itself rather than end-user debugging, but the information in there can nonetheless be helpful to understand what's going on, such as whether anything in there indicates that the GCS backend is making an API call and, if so, what settings it's using to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, and this was happening because I was running terraform commands from a different path than the one I was at.

```
terraform -chdir="another/path" apply
```

And then running the `output` command would fail with that error. Unless you `cd` to that path before running the `output` command.

```
cd "another/path"
terraform output
```

Comment: Really helpful! I had this issue with GA and this was the solution